# Query variables from URL hash javascript

Tags: 2013, query-string, cswp

I have a content search webpart that needs to show a list of events. It will page through month by month. The default month on the homepage will be the current month. Each time the user changes the month I would like to do a search on the month currently displayed.

I found [Query variables in SharePoint Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj683123.aspx) which shows all the tokens that I can access in my search query builder and I first tried putting the date into some parameters in the QueryString of the url.

> RefinableDate00>={QueryString.MyStartDate} AND
>   RefinableDate00<=QueryString.MyEndDate}

Where I change the url window.location.search string to include parameters that give values to start and end the currently displayed month. But each time I change the URL the page reloads and I would prefer not to do that.

I tried putting `MyStardDate` into the URL hash (since that won't reload the page), but I can't find a way for my query builder to read that.

Looking down the list of tokens on that page I can't see anything to just read a value from the page.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Okay so I found this http://sharepointificate.blogspot.com/2014/08/content-search-webpart-dynamic-filtering.html. It doesn't show me how to get a queryvariable from a hash, but it does show how to hack in and issue a new query based on variable data.

Answer (score 1):

Based on month changes, you should be passing a complete query including query strings (possibly refiners) so page load shouldn't affect the search results.

```
 var startdate= JSRequest.QueryString["MyStartDate"];
 var enddate= JSRequest.QueryString["MyEndDate"];
 var filtersArray = [];
 filtersArray.push("MyStartDate=" + startdate);
 filtersArray.push("MyEndDate=" + enddate);
 var filter = _spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath + "&" + filtersArray.join("&");
 window.location = filter;
```

You may build similar query with refiners only, and filter results without having to do a page refresh. Remember, refiners will append the hash so no page refresh, but query string performs page refresh.

```
var filtersArray = [];
var refinersArray = [];
.
.
//build arrays of query string and refiners
.
.
var refiners = '#Default={"k":"*","r":[' + refinersArray.join(",") + ']}';
var filter = _spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath + "?" + filtersArray.join("&") + refiners + '&';
window.location = filter;
```